# Scroll smoothly to specific position using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

How can I scroll smoothly to specific position using jQuery ?

I could scroll to top smoothly using jQuery with this code :

```
$("#id").animate({"scrollTop": $("#id").scrollTop() + 100});
```

But now I want to scroll to position for example 200 of a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 200}, "slow"); //you can change "slow" to a number amount or remove it (default is 500)
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UPRkm/

Answer (score -1):

i think you can do it by height....

```
$("#id").animate({

 height: '200px'

});
```

Comment: That would indeed animate the height of an element, but it wouldn't scroll the page.